# LDAP ACL for restricting applications with same user dn

Tags: openldap, ubuntu-14.04, access-control-list, sugarcrm

Currently we need to configure Group based LDAP login for our custom applications. We have applications named app1, app2 etc.

For restricting users to login for a particular application for eg app1 then for that user it should have attribute named **allowedService = app1**, for login to app2 that user need **allowedService = app2**

So in that way we created users.

Now for binding applications to ldap we created users like

cn=app1,ou=Applications,dc=prime,dc=ds,dc=geo,dc=com cn=app2,ou=Applications,dc=prime,dc=ds,dc=geo,dc=com

Now we configured LDAP ACL as follows:

```
olcAccess: {0}to attrs=userPassword,shadowLastChange
  by self write by anonymous auth
  by dn="cn=admin,dc=ds,dc=geo,dc=com" write
  by * none
olcAccess: {1}to dn.base=""
  by * read
olcAccess: {2}to dn.subtree="ou=People,dc=prime,dc=ds,dc=geo,dc=com" filter="(allowedService=app1)"
  by dn.exact="cn=app1,ou=Applications,dc=prime,dc=ds,dc=geo,dc=com" read
  by * break
olcAccess: {3}to dn.subtree="ou=People,dc=prime,dc=ds,dc=geo,dc=com" filter="(allowedService=app2)"
  by dn.exact="cn=app2,ou=Applications,dc=prime,dc=ds,dc=geo,dc=com" read
  by * break
olcAccess: {4}to dn.subtree="ou=People,dc=prime,dc=ds,dc=geo,dc=com" attrs="entry" by dn.sub="ou=Applications,dc=prime,dc=ds,dc=geo,dc=com" read
  by dn="cn=admin,dc=ds,dc=geo,dc=com" write
  by self read
  by * break
olcAccess: {5}to dn.subtree="ou=People,dc=prime,dc=ds,dc=geo,dc=com"
  by dn.exact="cn=app3,ou=Applications,dc=prime,dc=ds,dc=geo,dc=com" read
  by users read
olcAccess: {6}to dn.subtree="dc=prime,dc=ds,dc=geo,dc=com"
  by anonymous write
```

But when any application that doesn't support filter (Like suiteCRM) we created rule **olcAccess: {5}** and bind it with **app3** user but then the whole ACL is not working and all users can login to all application.

So can anyone please help us on it